# Blender for Beginners

Tags: performance

My nephew seems interested in doing 3d and all the great things Blender can do. I've done enough in Blender to love it.  But I can't afford a $4000  computer specified, especially not knowing if his interest is genuine.
 Is there an earlier version of blender that would run on Windows 7, just to see if he likes it?  The computer I'd like to give him is a Dell Optiplex 360, 4GB DDR2 Ram, 2.6 Ghz Dual Core Pentium. 250 GB hard drive. On board graphics card.  (I tried a slightly better graphics card, but couldn't get it to work.)

Comment: This questions is better suited to a forum, such as http://blenderartists.org

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! This is not a forum, so it works a little differently. You will get much better answers (to this kind of question) on a genuine forum, like BlenderArtists.com. The short answer, though, is that computer will run Blender just fine, especially for a beginner. It will probably not be able to use the GPU computer feature of Cycles, but it'll still be able to render both with Cycles and the Blender Internal renderer. Furthermore, just about any laptop in BestBuy that's more than $800 will run Blender REALLY well.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a \$4000 computer to run Blender, at home I have an HP pavillion laptop, core i7, intel graphic card with NVidia driver, so GPU render works, 8 GB ram, and it costs around \$550. I don't use it for final renders, I tried once 200% Full HD with 1024 samples, not surprisingly, Blender crashed, but for almost everything else, it is petfect, for a biginner he'll probably spend more time modeling and texturing, trying simple tasks, even when Blender crashes, it has one of the best recovery systems I've ever seen, and I worked for a long time with 3D "industry standard" software, and their recovery systems are not even close, I never lost significant amount of work using Blender "next to nothing".
I advise you to download Blender on your Dell, give it a try to test it's limits, if it can handle a render of 512 samples Full HD with 3 mesh lights and half a million mesh object, I think you're fine, if not, invest in a mid range desktop, after all, you don't want him to start using a broken instrument, this will be a very bad start, and I don't advise using an older version of Blender, I believe a version that will make a difference in hardware consumption will be too old, if he likes it, this will make the learning curve looks like wasting time and effort, learning to do workarounds that he doesn't need for a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is very well optimized for use on most computers. You don't necessarily need a fancy computer or fancy software to get started with CGI and other multimedia editors. There are ways to reduce the bottlenecks on the computer, and will allow the computer to utilize all of its cores (and its GPU if it has one!) Browse around in the User Preferences menu, in the "System" tab. There you'll find options to use more of computer's resources.

If you do choose to purchase a new computer, no computer will cost you \$4,000 unless you buy one of those AWFUL "premade" ones from the store. If you're after a high power or even average strength desktop computer, you can put one together yourself for anywhere from \$500 to \$1,500, assuming you purchase parts from Newegg or another site that specializes in getting the computer parts you need. Also, as suggested above, a standard laptop, purchased from best buy or an online store can easily run blender. I would recommend an Acer, Asus, or Dell laptop. Personally, I am running it on a Dell XPS 15, and it runs Blender flawlessly. The cheaper Dell laptops would work for a beginner, as the Acer and Asus laptops would.

Whatever option you choose to follow, kudos to your nephew for the interest in CGI! Just think about your various options and maybe see what he thinks as well, based on price limits and various software options (such as upgrades to Windows 10, if your computer allows it).

Answer (score -1):

I started to use blender with dual core duo and 4GB ddr2. You can do ONLY basic stuff with it. Sculpting, subdivision surfaces, simulations ect, are either slow or they will crash your computer. Also rendering stuff takes forever with those specs. Recently i bought some newer USED parts for my computer, including motherboard, i5 processor and 8GB ddr3 ram and now i can do much more in a much less time. Price for used parts was like 300-400 euros total. So i'd say that getting bit better computer for KEEP him interested as with too low spec computer spark might fade away. What comes to version for windows 7, i still would recommend to use newest one as operation system ain't problem with Blender, hardware makes bottlenecks.